# Linking android project's assets to folder on my hard drive

Tags: android, eclipse

Is there a way to link my android project's assets folder to a folder on my hard drive?  Then, I would be able to update a file on my hard drive, and it would be reflected in the assets folder.  If this is a possibility, are there known issues or problems that may arise?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: make a shortcut of assets folder in your hard drive.

Comment: wow, now i feel stupid. i just assumed eclipse would have made it more complicated. thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Also after every update, you have to build the project to get the change in apk!